# Access current instance of parent controller repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nested

I have:

```
<div ng-controller="fooControlle as fc">
    <div ng-repeat"fooObj in fc.fooCollection">
        <div ng-controller="barController as bc" ng-init="bc.init()">
            bc output here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to access fooObj from bc.init().

I tried:

```
ng-init="bc.init(fooObj)"
```

but fooObj is unknown.

By using $parent from my init function, I will see my collection but will not know which one is my current item.

Any thoughts?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you should pass the `$index` with your `$parent.fooObj` that will give you track on which element your there

```
<div ng-controller="fooControlle as fc">
    <div ng-repeat"fooObj in fc.fooCollection">
        <div ng-controller="barController as bc" ng-init="bc.init($parent.fooObj, $parent.$index)">
            bc output here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For making it more better your fooObj should have an unique value that could differentiate that it, like you should have something like `fooObj = {id: 1, .....}`

Answer (score 0):

personally the easiet would be to create a directive for the barController part and pass in the fooObj as a parameter to the directive

```
app.directive("foo", [function(){
    return {
         restrict: "E",
         controller: "barController",
         templateUrl: "",
         scope: {
            bar: "="
         }
    };
}]);
```

Then your html could be

```
<div ng-controller="fooControlle as fc">
    <div ng-repeat"fooObj in fc.fooCollection">
        <foo bar="fooObj"></foo>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for your answers. Pankaj, you showed me the way :)

It was dead simple in the end, with two options:

```
ng-init="bc.init($parent.fooObj)"
```

or

```
var init = function(){
    var foo = $parent.fooObj
}
```

Second way is clearly cleaner as there is no added value to send a value through a parameter when you can access it the same way from within the function.

> The key here is that I misunderstood what the **$parent** was here. I thought it was the **parent controller context** when it was the ng-repeat **current iteration context**.

Thanks for your assistance.